# Xcode8 ld- framework not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

After migrating to swift 3 I am having problem with HockeySDK pod. Few hours ago everything worked well but now I am unable to build it. I am getting Match-o  linker error, that framework wasn't found. I am having the same issue, when I work with previous commits, where everything was ok. I have tried delete derived data and restart system but without any results.Thanks for answer!

[image: error what i am getting by xcode]

Comment: Did you delete DerivedData? In picture you show i saw the path of SDK in DerivedData folder.

Comment: Yes I did, but derived data are created when I build it :) @nynohu

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods to manage dependancies?

Comment: Yes I did.
there is my podfile

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'SAStepperControl'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8’
    pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.0.2'
    pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
    pod 'HockeySDK'
#    pod 'BarcodeScanner'
end

target 'DFS - dev' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'DFS - prod' do
    shared_pods
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps may help:

1. Close Xcode
2. Delete DerivedData
3. Open Xcode, wait for indexing
4. Build the project

Comment: I am following these steps and it didn't work anyway. After indexing it show `failed`, so I am quite desperate, what to do

Comment: Do you convert all targets to Swift 3? Execute convert again, and examine all targets converted to Swift 3